# How do I display an empty string when a variable is not initialized?

Tags: basic

Im trying to display an empty string which is pretty straight forward, how is their a way to display an empty number for an integer? i have the example below.

```
Sub()

Dim s As String
Dim Number As Integer

'using a space in double quote
s = " "

'this will display an empty string, well not really empty but the space will make it empty
msgbox(s)
```

so basically im trying to do the same thing integer whereas when you use a msgbox for it
it displays nothing.

Comment: What variety of BASIC?

Comment: Why would you want an "empty" integer? You should always initialize your variables!

Comment: The reulst can be any of `undefined`, `0`, or just the random that happens to be in the memory space pointed to by the variable. Or you get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a function for your needs

```
function ShowNumberNonZero( n ) as string
    if n = 0 then
        ShowNumberNonZero = ""
    else
        ShowNumberNonZero = Trim(n)
    end if
end function
```

and then

```
msgbox(ShowNumberNonZero(Number))
```

Comment: @ Eduardo Molteni thats looks about right as to what I'm trying to accomplish, i will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set your integer at all, calling MsgBox will assign it 0 and it will display 0. The only way to make it so that it will display nothing would be to use an if statement or a function.

It might look something like this:

```
Private Sub Run()
    Dim number As Integer
    Message(number)
End Sub

Private Sub Message(ByVal input As Integer)
    If input = 0 Then
        MsgBox("")
    Else
        MsgBox(input)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As per the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help), please don't add signatures/sign-offs on your questions or answers.